# main activity not shown after splash

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my code. The  main activity won't run after splash screen 
and no errors appeared. 
It is a tabbed activity with a navigation drawer.
What might be the problem?
I tried several times. 
 I tried different activity in the app to run successfully, but it is not working with main activity.
Help me please.

====

splash screen

```html
package com.mohanadmarket.myapplication50

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.util.*

class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask(){
            override fun run() {
                val intent= Intent(this@SplashActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
             finish()
            }

        },5000L)
    }
}
```

mainfest

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mohanadmarket.myapplication50">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/sudacars_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

please tell me how to do it

thanxs!!

Comment: Try clean and build because your code is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to launch an activity from a background thread. So, what you have to do is to launch the activity on the UI thread.

Replace this code:

```
Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask(){
        override fun run() {
            val intent= Intent(this@SplashActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

    },5000L)
```

with

```
Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask(){
            override fun run() {
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post({
                      val intent= Intent(this@SplashActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
                      startActivity(intent)
                      finish()
                })
            }
}
```

or you can get rid of the `Timer` all together with

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
    val intent= Intent(this@SplashActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}, 5000L)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. But an alternative solution is to use `Handler`:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
     }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can go with alternative way. The most developers I have seen do like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(400)
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    setTheme(R.style.your_main_theme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(...)
    init()
}
```

Comment: What? No that's a terrible approach. You don't want to block the main thread. Use a PostDelayed handler and set the delay that way. That will come close to causing an ANR

Comment: No why? Anr is mostly cause by UI, I mean app blocks I/O operation. It looks better than creating new activity for splash, even it do not solve splash problem splash not avoidable.

Comment: If you're ever using Thread.sleep() you're probably doing something wrong. A post delayed handler doesn't block the thread it's being called on so it can be called on the Main(UI) thread. You can't update the UI on a different thread so your approach has you creating/starting threads (expensive operation), manually changing which thread you're operating on (more things can go wrong).

Comment: Might be, I always use like this, and I saw from others, also read about it. It works pretty good, but lemme dig deeper. Btw thanks for information.